# Win8 live tile for stack overflow?

Tags: feature-request

Is there, or will there be a Windows 8 live tile for stack overflow?

That might show notifications and reputation etc?

Comment: What's a live tile?

Comment: I guess it's one of those colored boxes in Windows 8 that tells you if you have new mail, tweets, facebook wall posts, whatever.  http://twimgs.com/informationweek/Ben/win8startweb.jpg

Comment: @random a fancy name for [Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229512.aspx)

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/3404/stackwatcher-live-tiles-for-windows-phone-7

Comment: Thanks for the links Robert. That one is for Windows Phone and only shows reputation. The only bit I'm really interested in is notifications. It would be quite useful to see the notifications on the start screen to stay up to the minute. Is there a way to programmatically get a user's stack exchange notifications? If so I might try making a tile myself.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeAWindows81PinnedLiveTileForYOURWebsiteInMinutes.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there, or will there be a Windows 8 live tile for stack overflow?

I don't know -- when are you going to write one?

In all seriousness, this sounds like a user-developed thing that would use [the public Stack API](https://stackapps.com/). Why not give it a try (seeing as how it sounds like you're one of the seven or eight people who have actually installed Windows 8?)

Comment: Cheers for the api link! I didn't find a 'notifications' property in the user objects so I presume there is no way to check if a user has notifications waiting... So it's a dead end.

Comment: Actually there must be, because right now on my Chrome toolbar I have a little button-applet-thingy called "Stack Alert" which does exactly that (shows the number of unread inbox items you have.) [Here is the Github site with the source!](https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Alert)

Comment: Oooo! Thanks Ernest!